# Boost with eclipse cannot find thread library

Tags: c++, eclipse, boost

I have downloaded and build the boost libraries with

```
bootstrap mingw
```

and

```
b2 toolset=gcc
```

and the libraries are created in

```
C:\Boost\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib
```

In eclipse I have added this directory as a library path

and added the library `libboost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_57` with and without the .a on the end.

the g++ line looks like

```
g++ "-LC:\\Boost\\boost_1_57_0\\stage\\lib" -o MyThread.exe main.o MyThread.o -llibboost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_57
```

and I get the error message

```
ld.exe: cannot find -llibboost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_57 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I add the `.a` it is appended to the error message as expected.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Specify the library without the `lib` prefix (which is the UNIX convention):

```
g++ "-LC:\Boost\boost_1_57_0\stage\lib" -pthread -o MyThread.exe main.o MyThread.o -libboost_thread-mgw49-mt-1_57
```

There's even a chance that (with the help of some standard convention symlinks) you could just say `-lboost_thread`.

**PS** Don't forget to use `-pthread` as well

Comment: Thank you, removing the lib did work, I appreciate your help.